# bzr - how to only commit one file pattern

Tags: include, commit, bazaar

I have a large hierarchical directory structure. I only want to commit files of one type (say *.c) and ignore all the other files. I know how to use .bzrignore to ignore specific file patters.. but is it possible to set something like a .bzrinclude file to only include a specific file pattern ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible because bazaar ignore files support regexes as patterns, using the `RE:` prefix:

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/patterns-help.html

So you just need to design a regular expression which matches everything except the files you're interested in.